# how to add a row in google spreadsheet and reference another cell?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a function to pull data from google finance and have it automatically log data to multiple sheets of a document.  I can't seem to get it to add a function as a function it always adds it as text until i edit the cell

```
function addLog() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var numLastRows = rows.getLastRow();

  sheet.appendRow(['2012/10/28','=b92','=c92','Log (auto)','','=index(GoogleFinance(C92,"price",A92);2;2)','','=h92','=i92','=j92','=k92']);


};
```

i couldn't figure out how to make it reference the cell above (row 92 in this case) either :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use the `setFormula()` method rather than `appendRow()`. Perhaps something like:

```
function addLog() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var numLastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  //add a row at end if necessary
  if (sheet.getMaxRows() == numLastRow) sheet.insertRowAfter(numLastRow);

  sheet.getRange(numLastRow + 1, 2, 1, 10)
    .setFormulas([['=b' + numLastRow,
                  '=c' + numLastRow,
                  '',
                  '',
                  '=index(GoogleFinance(C' + numLastRow + ',"price",A' + numLastRow + ');2;2)',
                  '',
                  '=h' + numLastRow,
                  '=i' + numLastRow,
                  '=j' + numLastRow,
                  '=k' + numLastRow]]);
  sheet.getRange(numLastRow + 1, 1).setValue('2012/10/28');
  sheet.getRange(numLastRow + 1, 4).setValue('Log (auto)');
}
```

---

To perform this action from the xth sheet through to the yth sheet (using zero-based index), I think the most efficient way would be:

```
function addAllLog() {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets();
  var x = 1;
  var y = 34;
  for (var i = x; i <= y; i++) {
    addLog(sheets[i]);
  }
}

function addLog(sheet) {
  var numLastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  //add a row at end if necessary
  if (sheet.getMaxRows() == numLastRow) sheet.insertRowAfter(numLastRow);

  sheet.getRange(numLastRow + 1, 2, 1, 10)
    .setFormulas([['=b' + numLastRow,
                  '=c' + numLastRow,
                  '',
                  '',
                  '=index(GoogleFinance(C' + numLastRow + ',"price",A' + numLastRow + ');2;2)',
                  '',
                  '=h' + numLastRow,
                  '=i' + numLastRow,
                  '=j' + numLastRow,
                  '=k' + numLastRow]]);
  sheet.getRange(numLastRow + 1, 1).setValue('2012/10/28');
  sheet.getRange(numLastRow + 1, 4).setValue('Log (auto)');
}
```

Comment: Hey adamL  thanks for the help  that worked exactly as i needed.

I have another question for you if you have the time :)  Let's say I have a bunch of sheets and wanted it to run on each of them when i activate the script. How would I go about looping through all of the tabs/sheets to do this?

Comment: i know what i want to do just don't know how to do it in javascript:

for (i=0; i<15;i++) {
  sheet(i).addLog();
}

(i don't really want to do it for EVERY sheet, just the first X which i will have to change if i need to change it, that's not a problem)

Comment: I believe i have this working now



`    function addAllLog() {
      var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var allSheets = ss.getSheets();
      // build array of all sheets
      for (var i in allSheets) { 
        if (i == 0) { continue;}  // do not do first sheet
        if (i >= 35) { continue;}  // do not do any sheets after this
        ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(allSheets[i].getName()));
        addLog();
      }
    }

`
It's actually a lot slower than i thought it would be... see any way to speed it up @AdamL?

Comment: Have added to my answer +Cactus Dude.